# Plotting spaces spanned by parameters

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have three coordinate functions of a vector of parameters:
`x[q]`, `y[q]`, `z[q]` where `q` is at least a three-dimensional vector in some domain $Q$. Is it possible to plot in 3D the space spanned by `q`? By that I mean all the triplets `{x',y',z'}` such that there is at least one `q` in $Q$ such that `x[q]=x'`, `y[q]=y'`, `z[q]=z'`? Of course I would be happy if this worked with intervals (say $Q$ is the unit cube). And of course I would be happy with the surface of the subset.

I need to quickly check that this is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So any other method is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your three scalar functions `x`, `y`, and `z` have been defined, you'd do something like this:

```
n = 3;
q = Array[q1, n]; 
RegionPlot3D[
 Length[FindInstance[(x @@ q == x1) && (y @@ q == y1) && (z @@ q == z1), q]] > 
  0, {x1, -1, 1}, {y1, -1, 1}, {z1, -1, 1}]
```

Here, `n` is the dimension of $Q$. This is all I can do without knowing how the unknowns in your question are actually defined.